# if or statement isn't working correctly

Tags: php

Im having problem with a if statement.
This is the if statement:

```
if($userID != $_SESSION["sess_id"] || $creator != $_SESSION["sess_id"]){

echo "Success";
exit;

}
```

This is the values for the variables:

```
$userID = 24;
$creator = 13;
$_SESSION["sess_id"] = 13;
```

So for short:

```
if(24 != 13 || 13 != 13){

echo "Success";
exit;

}
```

Why is Success still showing?

**Note that this is just a shortened version of my code, No one of the variables are set like this but the values are right.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `24 != 13` is still true. For `OR` it suffices that one of the sides is true.

```
if (true || false) //true
if (true && false) //false
if (false || false) //false
if (false && false) //false
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `||OR` and that only needs one statement to be true and in your case `24 != 13` is true

Answer (score 1):

because you use the "||". It's an "or".
You must use "&&" (and).

```
if($userID != $_SESSION["sess_id"] && $creator != $_SESSION["sess_id"]){
```

Comment: I was about to put that

Answer (score 0):

The expression `$userID != $_SESSION["sess_id"]` -> `24 != 13` is satisfied(TRUE) so that it pass into the condition, You have used `OR` condition, either any one condition `true` block get executed.